# Android System.err out of the blue

Tags: android

While running my app, LogCat suddenly shows this barrage of orange-colored messages (warnings) which seem to be totally unrelated to my app (and certainly *not* having the same pid):

```
05-01 12:00:03.732: WARN/System.err(1836): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://gh-pages.clockworkmod.com/ROMManagerManifest/premium_imei.js
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:653)
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.StreamUtility.downloadUrl(StreamUtility.java:46)
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.Helper$1.run(Helper.java:164)
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.Helper.isPremium(Helper.java:178)
05-01 12:00:03.752: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService.checkForUpdates(DownloadService.java:314)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.koushikdutta.rommanager.DownloadService.onStart(DownloadService.java:401)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-01 12:00:03.762: WARN/System.err(1836):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-01 12:00:14.202: WARN/System.err(1836): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 12:00:14.202: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.paypal.android.a.h.a(Unknown Source)
05-01 12:00:14.202: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.paypal.android.a.a.j(Unknown Source)
05-01 12:00:14.202: WARN/System.err(1836):     at com.paypal.android.a.f.run(Unknown Source)
```

What does this mean? Is this is a bug in Android? A bug in some other external app or service running in the background?

How do I tell whether this has anything to do with my app-in-development?

(**Note**: My app doesn't use PayPal or ROM Manager in any way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some kind of error occurring in what the ROM Manager is trying to do - probably a periodic check for new releases.

I wouldn't expect this has anything to do with your application, unless you see it happen during your application multiple times.  And even then, I'd leave a logcat open when your app is not running and see if it's happening frequently.

You might want to think if you want to leave that rom manager installed/enabled...

Comment: Thanks + 1. I checked the list of running processes and the 'Manage running applications' in my phone's settings, looking for the ROM Manager to kill it, but couldn't find one. It probably died when it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using them then it's just those services running in the background.  Nothing you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should filter to `'Show only selected application'`?

[image]

That way you'll see only stuff related to your app.