# How to check whether TtsService (or an Android service) is stopped?

Tags: android, android-service, text-to-speech

For reasons [beyond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849745/android-system-err-out-of-the-blue) my app's control, `TtsService` is stopped **by the system**, providing only Log.i() hints in LogCat:

```
05-01 12:01:55.662: INFO/TtsService(1791): Stopping
05-01 12:01:55.662: INFO/TtsService(1791): Stopped
```

I would like to be able to handle this situation from within my app.

Is there a way (a callback or a system call) to detect when this happens?

If not, is there a way to check whether the TTS service is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following method to check whether service is running or not.

```
ServiceName = "package.service".\\service name
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context ctx, String serviceName) 
    {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceName.equalsIgnoreCase(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.v(TAG,serviceName+": Service running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```